# Django REST Framework how to allow DELETE only without pk

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to create an endpoint:

`DELETE /users` (deleted ids in the request body)

So, i created a class `UserViewSet`, that extends `mixins.DestroyModelMixin`  and `GenericViewSet` and implemented the method `def delete(self, request)`, it works for request `DELETE /users`, but the problem is that user can send `DELETE /users/5` request and then i got an error 'Not found` (user with the current pk is not found, because i don't have it).

I want to forbid send `DELETE /users/{id}` requests and allow only `DELETE /users`.

How can i do this?

I tried to use decorator `@action(methods=['delete'], detail=True)` for the delete method, but its doesn't change anything.

Also i tried to use this signature:

```
def delete(self, request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        return Response(data='PK is not allowed in DELETE method')
```

For some reason it doesn't even match this method with `DELETE/{id}` and i still get the error 'Not found'.

**UPD**. I delete `mixins.DestroyModelMixin` from the extend classes and now `DELETE /users` works but `DELETE/{id}` gives me 404 (Page not found) when i try to send DELETE with id.

I would like something like method not allowed

**UPD2.**

Code:

```
def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    raise exceptions.MethodNotAllowed('DELETE with PK')
```

Works for me, but i think this is the bad solution...

Answer (score 0):

You get `404 (Page not found)` because you don't have `/users/<int:id>` in your URLConf.

Comment: There are two different `not found`, first is that cannot find user with this pk but request is ok, and second is which you wrote, but to forbid the use of such a method signature, you need to use the override of the viewset methods, and not through the url config, you can read `upd2`, i override this method and this is works, but i think it's not an optimal solution